# Validar Imagen al mostrar asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Estoy realizando un mostreo de una imagen almacenado en una base de datos de SQL Server pero como una búsqueda, les explico para que se muestre tiene que buscar por una fecha y una oficina. Y cuando lo encuentra se muestra. La verdad si me llega a salir pero cuando en la búsqueda no está la imagen me sale un error como este:

> No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.DBNull' al tipo
>   'System.Byte[]'.

Este es mi código actual:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                 <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> Seleccione la Fecha :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFecha" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td>
                  <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupButtonID="txtFecha" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFecha" Format="yyyy/MM/dd"> </cc1:CalendarExtender> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Seleccionar la Zona : </td>
                <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="dprAgencia" class="form-control" runat="server" style="width: 226px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dprAgencia_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Buscar" OnClick="Button1_Click1" /> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Limpiar" OnClick="Button2_Click1" Visible="false" /> </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
     <div>
       <asp:ListView ID="ListImagenes" runat="server" Visible="true">

                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table id="Table2" runat="server" class="table-responsive">
                                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" border="3" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                            <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                                                <th id="Th3" runat="server" style="text-align: center;">Rubro</th>
                                                <th id="Th1" runat="server" style="text-align: center;">Usuario Registro</th>
                                                <th id="Th2" runat="server" style="text-align: center;">Recibo</th>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                        </LayoutTemplate>

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                       <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#   Eval("tarea") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#   Eval("UsuarioAtencion") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("filecontent"))  %>' runat="server" Style="width: 150px; height: 150px" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" />
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function () {

                                            $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').popover({
                                                html: true,
                                                trigger: 'hover',
                                                content: '<img src="' + '<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("filecontent")) %>' + '" id="popover_img" Style="width: 500px" />'
                                            }).hover(function () {
                                                $('#popover_img').attr('src', $(this).data('img'));
                                            });

                                            $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').mouseover(function () {
                                                $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').popover('show')
                                            });

                                            $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').mouseout(function () {
                                                $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').popover('hide')
                                            });
                                        });

                                    </script>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:ListView>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Este es mi código en el `code behind`:

```
  protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
            SqlCommand sqlCommand;
            DataTable dt;
            dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Sp_MostrarImagen", connection);

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.Date);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@oficina", SqlDbType.Int);

                sqlCommand.Parameters["@fecha"].Value = txtFecha.Text;
                sqlCommand.Parameters["@oficina"].Value = dprAgencia.SelectedValue;


                adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;


                adapter.Fill(dt);

                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();

                ListImagenes.DataSource = SelectFotoPrueba();
                ListImagenes.DataBind();
                ListImagenes.Visible = true;
                connection = null;



            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                dt.Dispose();
                Button1.Visible = false;
                Button2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Este es mi código en el procedimiento almacenado:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_MostrarImagen] @fecha DATE
    ,@oficina INT
AS
BEGIN
    --select idatenciontarea,filename,filecontent,active  from TTareasAtender
    SELECT tarea
        ,idatenciontarea
        ,UsuarioAtencion
        ,filename
        ,filecontent
        ,active
    FROM TTareasAtender
    WHERE year(FechacumplimientoOriginal) = year(@fecha)
        AND MONTH(FechacumplimientoOriginal) = MONTH(@fecha)
        AND day(FechacumplimientoOriginal) = day(@fecha)
        AND oficina = @oficina
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
END
```

**En la SelectedFotoPrueba**

```
  public DataTable SelectFotoPrueba()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
            SqlCommand sqlCommand;
            DataTable dt;
            dt = new DataTable();


            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("ImagenDaniel", connection);

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int);


                sqlCommand.Parameters["@opt"].Value = 1;


                adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;


                adapter.Fill(dt);

                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
                connection = null;

                return dt;

            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                dt.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

En esta línea:

```
            ListImagenes.DataSource = SelectFotoPrueba();
```

Tienes que validar si alguna imagen es null, que tienes dentro del método `SelectFotoPrueba();` ?

Lo que yo haria es pasar as `ListImagenes` un `dataTable` que no contenta los valores de imagen en `null`, algo así:

```
var dtOk = new DataTable();
foreach(var dr in datatableImagenes){
    if(dr["columnaImagen"] != null){
        dtOk.addNewRow(dr); //De este modo dtOK tendra solo los row con imagenes
    }
}
```

Comment: si en mi metodo SelectFotoPrueba lo edite y lo puse al final pero el metodo solo es un procedure que jala a la imagen de ese campo que tiene la imagen pero al en ese campo que estan nullos y no hay imagenes y eso queria validarlo si es nullo que no muestre nada.

Comment: Un apunte. Cuando en el `ItemArray` de un `DataRow` no hay datos o sea ha rellenado vacío no es `null`, es `System.DBNull` por lo que igual te convendría editar la respuesta para añadir esa condición. `dr["columnaImagen"] is System.DBNull`